# Sending a sms from android device

Tags: android, multithreading, sms

I got a class that calculates my location and print it on the screen.
Now I want to send a sms every x time with that adress to a certain number.
So that requires the sleep method I guess which means I need a class that extends Thread .. but how that class would take the TextView string from the other one? how they will be connected to each other?
btw I found this code somewhere in this forum for sending a sms:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("sms:"+ phoneNumber)));
```

Thanks in advanced!!

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452808/sending-and-receiving-mms-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use SmsManager,

```
 String Text = "My location is: " +
    "Latitude = " + current_lat +
    "Longitude = " + current_lng;

    SmsManager sender=SmsManager.getDefault();
    sender.sendTextMessage("9762281814",null,Text , null, null);
```

Comment: Thats a nice way to send a sms but I need to send a sms every x time which means it has to be done through a thread.

Comment: Ok I done it by sending the class reference to the other class the sends the sms and then it can gets the TextView text. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your Thread related stuff in an Async task, and pass it a Context parameter of the current activity. This way you could call the `Context.findViewById()` inside the `doInBackGround()` method of the async task. This way you'd not even be performing any blocking action on the main thread (which would lead you to another exception in the future).

```
public void SendSmsTask extends AsyncTask<Context, Void, Void> {
  @Override
  protected Void doInBackGround(Context... contexts) {
    for(Context con : contexts) {
      TextView abc = context.findViewById(<textview Id>);
      // send your sms after this
    }
  }
... // remaining functions and logic
}
```

You can start this task from your activity using:

```
new SendSmsTask().execute(this);
```